# C# Sorting DataGridView by clicking header gives incorrect order

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a C# WinForms application, which has seven columns, and is used for two scenarios, call them Scenario A and Scenario B, which use exactly the same data but show different columns:-

The first column is never visible (it's an internal ID)

The second and third columns are always visible

The fourth and fifth columns are visible in Scenario A

The sixth and seventh columns are visible in Scenario B

The data source is a binding source, and the second to seventh columns are all set up in exactly the same way in the Columns Collection property of the DataGridView. The only difference between each column is the HeaderText, DataPropertyName and Width.

Specifically, all six columns have SortMode set to Automatic, and ColumnType to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.

Each column is a databound column, bound to one of the fields of the binding source.

All columns show the correct data.

If I click on the header for the second or third column, in either Scenario, they sort correctly, both ascending and descending.

If I am in Scenario A, which shows columns four and five, and click on the headers for either of those, they both sort correctly, both ascending and descending.

If I am in Scenario B, which shows columns six and seven, and click on the headers for either of those, they both sort INCORRECTLY, both ascending and descending.

Even stranger, columns six and seven don't even give the same results each time.

For example, let's say the data in columns six is empty, empty, A, A, B, B, B, C, D, D

The data is initially sorted by column two, so column six is unsorted.

I click the header for column six, the sort arrow shows ascending, but the data is empty, B, empty, D, C, A, B, A, D, B

I click the header for column six again, the sort arrow now shows descending, but the data is B, empty, C, D, D, empty, A, B, A, B

I click the header for column six again, the sort arrow shows ascending, but the data is now empty, D, C, A, empty, B, B, A, D, B, different from the previous ascending order

I click the header for column six again, the sort arrow now shows descending, but the data is now D, empty, A, B, B, empty, C, D, A, B, different from the previous descending order.

However, after the third cycle, it seems to settle on an order, still not properly sorted but at least stable, so every ascending order is the same and every descending order is the same from now on, until I close and re-open the form.

There is no sorting code at all for that grid, it's left to handle it itself.

The code is very simple (stripped down to just relevant bits, and names changed for clarity):-

In the Load event of the form, the data is fetched and assigned to the binding source. It's exactly the same data regardless of the Scenario.

I then set the Visible flag to true or false for columns four to seven depending on the scenario (all four columns are set to visible = true in the designer).

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
    SetColumnsVisible();
}

private void GetData()
{
    _bindingSource.DataSource = _dataService.GetData();
}

private void SetColumnsVisible()
{
    if (_scenario == ScenarioA)
    {
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnFour"].Visible = true;
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnFive"].Visible = true;
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnSix"].Visible = false;
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnSeven"].Visible = false;
    }
    if (_scenario == ScenarioB)
    {
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnFour"].Visible = false;
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnFive"].Visible = false;
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnSix"].Visible = true;
        dgvData.Columns["ColumnSeven"].Visible = true;
    }
    dgvData.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
}
```

All the remaining code for the form is unrelated to sorting, and it all works correctly.

I put in an event to catch column header clicks, to see if perhaps it was trying to sort by one of the non-visible columns, but the column index is correct in each case, e.g. if I'm in Scenario B and click the header for column six, the column index is 5 (as index starts from 0).

Not that sorting by a different column would explain the different results the first few times, but was worth a shot.

Anyone ever had a DataGridView just produce random results when you click a column to sort it?

Or got any thoughts on how to fix it?

To sum up:-

Exactly the same data is used either way.

The columns are set up exactly the same.

There is no sorting code, just the default DataGridView sorting.

Columns two to five sort correctly every time.

Columns six and seven sort incorrectly every time, and the first three times will be different before settling down.

Comment: Show examples of data that is not in correct order.  The order is correct, just not what you want.

Comment: Your columns are all Text based types? i.e. DataGridViewTextBoxColumn?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the empty results were null strings (as the data was null), which was confusing the sorting, even though other grids are quite happy with them.

Changed the nulls to empty strings in the data fetch, and it sorts quite happily now.